# Bimodules and Tesnors in TQFT

Tags: category-theory, modules, tensor-products, cobordism

I'm reading [this](http://www.math.harvard.edu/theses/senior/lee/lee.pdf) paper and am wondering if the quote below found on page 17 near the bottom makes sense.

> We need a way to produce a $B\otimes C-A\otimes C$ bimodule: to do
>   this consider the module $M\otimes_k C$.

What is a $B\otimes C-A\otimes C$ bimodule?  Or is this a typo?

Comment: Do you know what a bimodule is?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  I know what a bimodule is but I've never seen that notation before.  How do I read that?  Is it just $B\otimes C$ minus $A\otimes C$?

Comment: A bimodule is a left module over one ring and a right module over another ring. That notation names the two rings.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan That clears it up, so you could also write $_{B\otimes C}M_{A\otimes C} $.

Comment: Yes, exactly. $\,$